# How can I read a text file containing Unicode, into a wchar_t pointer using wifstream?

Tags: c++, ifstream, wchar-t, wifstream

I'm trying to read Unicode characters from a text file into a **wchar_t** pointer array, using **wifstream**. Here is a code snippet:

```
locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));
std::wifstream inputFile("gsmCharacterSet.txt", std::ifstream::binary | std::ifstream::ate);
int length = inputFile.tellg();
inputFile.seekg(0,inputFile.beg);
wchar_t *charArray = new wchar_t[length];
inputFile.read(charArray,length);
```

It's not working. The length returned is 252 which is the correct file size in bytes. However, the array remains empty.

The following condition returns **true**:

```
if ( inputFile.peek() == std::wifstream::traits_type::eof() )
    cout << "File is empty";
```

I'm compiling the program on Linux using g++.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't use `wchar_t` in c++. Use `std::string` as it automatically handles unicode.

Comment: @iharob know I can use `std::string`, but I'm required Not to use it.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi No it doesn't.